# convert 2D video input sequence to 3D video

Tags: image-processing

how can be the depth information can be extracted form 2D video sequences to convert for 3D video.Please suggest me with some algorithms or codes to do this with matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Depth information cannot be "extracted" from a 2D video simply because it isn't there. The best you can do is employ techniques that estimate depth, some fully automatic and some that are operator assisted. Of course the latter give much better quality.

One of the typical ways in which depth can be generated from a 2D video consists in analyzing the motion of different parts of the scene. Consider, for example, a scene shot from the window of a moving car. Objects that are closer to the camera, like cars, trees or buildings will be moving much faster than objects that are far in the background like clouds in the sky, so analyzing the speed at which the objects move can give you a good estimation of their distance to the camera, information that in turn can be used to generate a depth map and then a stereo picture.

A simple and less effective approach is to play the same video on the left and right eyes, but with one of the eyes delayed by one or more frames. For videos that have lateral motion this technique works really well. See [this page](http://3dvision-blog.com/1220-2d-to-3d-realtime-video-conversion-script-for-avisynth-v0-3/) for an AviSynth script that generates this transformation for any video in real time.

For a brief summary of techniques for estimating depth in 2D videos see the Wikipedia page on [2D to 3D conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_to_3D_conversion).